# getIdentifier not working to get id of resource

Tags: android

I am using getIdentifier to get the id of a raw resource by name. It is not working though, and I am certain to be using it correctly. Is there something that I am missing?

I have verified that the raw resources exist under the string I am giving it. I have also cleaned the project to make sure that R.java is correct.

```
id = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier("file_name", null , ctx.getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the methods needs the `type/` (or `defType`) param. Should be something like `drawable` or `layout` depending on the resource directory.

You can include it in the first String parameter :

```
id = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/file_name", null , ctx.getPackageName());
```

or pass it as the second parameter :

```
id = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier("file_name", "drawable", ctx.getPackageName());
```

Also, be sure to exclude the file extension from the file name you're passing. If the methods still returns `0`, check if `file_name` corresponds to an id somewhere in your `R.java` file.

Comment: I tried both ways. I tried with the raw directory provided in the second argument  as "raw".

Comment: If I don't have a `file_name` in my `R.java` because I'm building dynamically how can I do? I've got the **path** and  `File imgFile = new File(arrListspotpics.get(0));`

Answer (score 0):

Way late, but I think this issue is related to an incorrect application id.

It is configured in you app's module build.gradle file:

```
android{
 defaultConfig {
     applicationId "your application id goes here"
```

From what I have observered, It seems the packageName for the generated R file is base on the value of the packageName in the Manifest.xml file. However the context.GetPackageName seems to be returning the value of the configured applicationId. If they are the same, then there's no issue.  If they are different than a call to resources.getIdentifier(…,..., ctx.getPackageName()) will fail to find the identifier.

I'm not sure that the above paragraph is totally correct.  What I actually observed was that If I changed the applicationId to match name of the PackageName in the Manifest.xml file then the issue I had on not getting a resource identifier using the getIdentifer method went away. I have to admit, I was somewhat surprised that corrected my problem.